# can we turn all radio signals to a single recieving antenna

Tags: transistors

Is it possible to turn all the radio signals to a single recieving antenna? Or,simply how can we receive all radio signals by
 a single recieving antenna.or is it possible to overlap many similar radio signals to enhance it's strength.

Comment: which antenna are you taking about, microstrip, or physical aperture antennas?Its quite possible in case of patch and microstip antennas, but in case of physical antenna you are limited due to physical parameters, but still you can catch upto a large range, but a universal antenna is still a scientific-fiction,all the antennas have  a white-band but their selective gain is their limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is work being done on so called configurable antennas like this from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconfigurable_antenna) [image]

The idea being that you use rf switches or other methods to reconfigure the antenna to be more efficient at the frequency you are currently trying to receive.

That's a little more advanced than your normal antenna.

Answer (score 1):

An antenna can receive all frequencies, but is usually only efficient at a small range (depends on the dimensions of the antenna).

If you can get two radio signals to be identical and arrive at the receiving antenna at exactly the same time (1 microsecond difference is not good enough) then they will add up and you get more signal. If the two signals are not the same or one of them is delayed, you get interference and the receiving signal quality goes down since now the receiver has to distinguish between the "good" signal and "bad" signal.

This is how radio jamming works - produce a signal that is powerful enough and aim it at the receiver - now the receiver cannot "hear" the transmitter because of the noise that you add.